# Open website if there is error 

Tags: inno-setup

Is there any way to open a website link when user cancel installation or there is error during install ?

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following:

```
procedure CallPage;
var
  ErrorCode: Integer;
begin
  ShellExec(’open’, ‘http://www.yourdomain.com/xxxxxx’, ”, ”, SW_SHOWNORMAL, ewNoWait,    ErrorCode);
end;
```

Where xxxxx is page you want to be called. You can even pass parameters when calling the page.

Comment: how can I call CallPage , I do not know much about innosetup .