# How to show a web page after an error in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

If Inno Setup exits with an error I want to show the standard error message box, then display my FAQ web page.

Displaying a web page seems fairly straight forward:

[Open website if there is error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628894/open-website-if-there-is-error)

But how do I trap the error so I can call this function? There doesn't seem to be an error event:

http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptevents.htm